# flutter dart How to list all values ​of a specific key value in a map

Tags: dart

I want to get the value of 'id' of map as list.

Expected output: `[1,35, 93, 82, 28]`

```dart
[{'id': 1, 'name':'flutter', 'title':'dart'},

{'id': 35, 'name':'flutter', 'title':'dart'},

{'id': 93, 'name':'flutter', 'title':'dart'},
  
{'id': 82, 'name':'flutter', 'title':'dart'},

{'id': 28, 'name':'flutter', 'title':'dart'},
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map` to iterate through each object and get the value you want:

```
void main() {
  final list = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
    {'id': 35, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
    {'id': 93, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
    {'id': 82, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
    {'id': 28, 'name': 'flutter', 'title': 'dart'},
  ];

  final idList = list.map((e) => e['id']).toList(); // [1, 35, 93, 82, 28]
}
```

Comment: The answer was helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: @lhyojin0821 if it solved your issue please mark it as accepted